# Database query API error construction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, error-handling, sequelize.js

I'm working on a simple API that performs an INSERT query into a SQL database, using information supplied from a form clients would fill out on the front end. I'm curious if there is a preferred way when it comes to constructing the error message regarding query errors.

Using a concrete example, I have a form to be filled out by users with attributes A, B, and C. In the SQL database, they're all enforced with a "NOT NULL" constraint. Therefore, if an empty form was submitted, the following error object would be returned:

```
{
...
errors:
  [ ValidateErrorItem {
      message: "model.a cannot be null"
      type: "..."
      path: "..." 
      value: "..."
      .. },
    ValidateErrorItem {
      message: "model.b cannot be null"
      type: "..."
      path: "..." 
      value: "..."
      .. },
    ValidateErrorItem {
      message: "model.c cannot be null"
      type: "..."
      path: "..." 
      value: "..."
      .. },
  ]
}
```

How would one typically construct an error message to be display to the user (other than simply showing "An error occurred with the query")?

Note: I know that this scenario can be prevented using front end validation, but other things can go wrong (besides non-null validation), so this is just a simple example when an error occurs, not necessarily what I'd do in practice.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of validations should be performed for each api request. I prefer to use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi).

Joi will throw error anytime the schema does not match with what you are expecting.  For example

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  modelA: Joi.string().required(),
  modelB: Joi.string().required(),
  modelC: Joi.string().required(),
});

const myObj = { modelA: 'modelA' };
console.log(Joi.validate(myObj, schema));
```

The above code will throw an error `{ ValidationError: child "modelB" fails because ["modelB" is required]`

You can also add customer error message like this

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  modelA: Joi.string().required(),
  modelB: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('Was expecting a string')),
  modelC: Joi.string().required(),
});
const myObj = { modelA: 'modelA' };
console.log(Joi.validate(myObj, schema));
```

This will throw an error

```
   Error: Was expecting a string
```

These messages can be parsed by front-end and shown as such.